# Any alternative for webform_mysql_views

Tags: views, 6, webforms

I am using postgresql as database. I want to create views of webform submissions. is there anything similar to [webform_mysql_views](http://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) for postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module.

> Data module helps you model, manage and query related sets of tables. It offers an administration interface and a low level API for manipulating tables and accessing their contents. Data module provides Views integration for displaying table data and Drupal search integration for searching table content.

Comment: Yes I used data.It is useful to create tables, adopt tables. but does not complete my requirements.

Comment: After more time waste I change my need and use Webform_table_element which also shows table view of webform submissions.

Comment: I also use Webform_Views_Submitted_Data but it can't show me results.